# Resize bin size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to change the bin size of the Y-axis for better visualisation. How can I change that? Could you please help me?

Here is my code:

```
age_occ = df_rename.groupby(['Age', 'Occupation'])['Occupation'].count().unstack('Age').fillna(0)
ax_age_occ = age_occ.plot.bar(figsize=(15,7),stacked=False)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Occupation')
```

Here is my graph:

[image]

Comment: The default gaps between the groups are quite wide.  You could try  `age_occ.plot.bar(....,width=0.98)`. (`width` is the width of one full group, with `width=1` the groups would be touching)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your valuable suggestions. Could you please tell me how to resize the bin size?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any binning.  It's unclear how the age groups are created.  Depending on what you want to show, you might take together age groups.  And/or you might group together some of the occupations. Everything strongly depends on what exactly you want to show with your plot.